# What's the AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps folder for?

Tags: windows-10

Tried to run a python command today and it opened up the page to install Python from the Windows Store for some reason. Somehow a zero-byte "program" called python.exe got installed here and it has precedence over the actual Python installation in the $PATH?

```
PS C:\> where.exe python
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
```

Contents of the folder:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        11/3/2019   3:02 AM                Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe
d-----       10/10/2019   8:06 PM                Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
d-----       10/24/2019   3:59 AM                Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe
d-----       10/25/2019   2:36 PM                Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_8wekyb3d8bbwe
-a---l       10/25/2019   2:36 PM              0 GameBarElevatedFT_Alias.exe
-a---l       10/10/2019   8:06 PM              0 MicrosoftEdge.exe
-a---l        11/3/2019   3:02 AM              0 python.exe
-a---l        11/3/2019   3:02 AM              0 python3.exe
-a---l       10/24/2019   3:59 AM              0 wt.exe
```

I removed it using command prompt, but I'm very curious how it appeared there overnight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typing “python” on Windows 10 (version 1903) command prompt opens Microsoft store](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor). This is a feature of Windows 10  version 1903.  The answers to the duplicate question will resolve your issue.