# Why are there empty files in %localappdata%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\?

Tags: windows

I found some `.exe` files in

```
C:\Users\liaoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\
```

They are all 0B.

What are these files used for?

Comment: Overall, this is a perfectly understandable question.  The only confusing part may be why you have it tagged [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux] -- You don't mention anything about WSL in the question.  I'm guessing that the `wsl.exe` is one of the 0 byte files?

Comment: I'll answer in the comments for now, and move it to an answer if/when it gets reopened.  These are App Execution Aliases, which are links to Microsoft Store apps that are included in your path.  For example, I have `python.exe` there, which allows the Windows Store Python installation to run from the command-line easily.  The Store version of WSL is also there as `wsl.exe`, and overrides the `wsl.exe` that is installed with Windows in `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe`.  Even some "base" Windows apps like Paintbrush (`pbrush.exe`) are now installed via the Store in recent Windows releases.

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14821/1210833).

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1498703/whats-the-appdata-local-microsoft-windowsapps-folder-for) question was asked 3 years ago, and was closed as a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor) question, which I suspect is indirectly a duplicate of this question. Since I originally closed this question, thinking the question needed to be clarified, I cannot actually vote to close it as a duplciate