# How do I alias python3 on Windows?

Tags: python, environment-variables, path, alias, python3

I want to alias `python3` to `python` on windows. I have already removed the alias for the microsoft store as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1461471). However `python3` is still not a known alias. How to I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using doskey and create a macro named *python3* that will run Python.exe similar to the default macro *py* that exists

Comment: You have the alias built-in if you install Python 3 from the Windows Store (rather than using winget or the python.org installer).

Comment: @Danra But that's not an option if you already have an installation or don't want to use the Windows Store.

Comment: Sure. It's unfortunate the other installation venues don't provide the same convenience built-in.

Answer (score 29):

> I want to alias `python3` to `python` on Windows.

You haven't mentioned what release of Python you are using (e.g. "vanilla" [Python](https://www.python.org/), Anaconda, SciPy, etc.), but if I am not misunderstanding, this likely shouldn't be necessary. For Windows versions of Python (i.e. not WSL), `python3` is not typically a standard alias. That is, the Python 3.x executable is usually just `python` (`python.exe`).

Be aware that `python.exe` should be in a folder listed in your Windows Path if you want to access it as just `python`. You can find a refresher on editing Windows Path variables [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/).

If you meant the reverse (i.e. you want to run Python 3.x with `python3`), then there are at least a few possible approaches (each item below is a separate option):

1. Make symbolic link called `python3.exe` to your preferred copy of Python 3.x with [mklink](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink):

   ```
   mklink "C:\path\to\symlink\python3.exe" "C:\path\to\Python3\python.exe"
   ```
2. Copy the `python.exe` file in your preferred installation of Python 3.x and rename the copied executable `python3.exe`.
3. If you aren't set on specifically using `python3` and have the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) (`py.exe`) installed which comes with "vanilla" Python from [python.org](https://www.python.org/), you can use:

   ```
   # Use the "default" installation of Python 3.x, 
   # as detected by the Python Launcher for Windows.

   py 3
   ```

   or:

   ```
   # Use a specific version of Python 3.x if you have more
   # than one version installed, outside of a virtual environment.

   py 3.8
   ```
4. Create a Windows batch file called `python3.bat` with the following information:

   *ex. python3.bat*

   ```
   C:\path\to\Python3\python.exe %*
   ```
5. You can also alias Python Launcher for Windows (`py.exe`) calls in a similar manner in `python3.bat` e.g.:

   *ex. python3.bat*

   ```
   py 3 %*
   ```

   or:

   *ex. python3.bat*

   ```
   py 3.8 %*
   ```

With all the options above, any "python3" file you wish to access from the command line (i.e. any symbolic link, a renamed executable copy, `py.exe` or `python3.bat`) must be in a folder located in your Windows Path.

**Notes**

- These options obviously do not include any option to "alias" `python.exe` at the command line (e.g. via [doskey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey) macros, as mentioned in the comments, or possibly via actual alias commands specific to a given terminal). It also ignores the possibility that some distributions of Python could (theoretically) already come with a `python3` alias.
- Creating a symbolic link with `mklink` on Windows may require administrative privileges on versions of Windows earlier than some early releases of Windows 10.
- When creating a symbolic link, be certain to include the file extension (`.exe`). This is not optional if you want the link to work correctly.
- It is likely best to leave any renamed executable copy (option 2) in the same folder as the original `python.exe`.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the Windows PowerShell and not the command prompt, you can use the following code:

```
Set-Alias -Name python3 -Value python
```

or use the following code:

```
Set-Alias -Name python3 -Value "C:\Python39\python.exe"
```

Note that this is a temporary Alias for the current session, to make it permanent; you have to copy the above command into an empty text file and name it Profile.ps1 file and copy it to one of the following folders:

if you are using PowerShell 7:

```
{My Documents Folder}/PowerShell
```

if you are using Windows PowerShell which comes by default in Windows 10:

```
{My Documents Folder}/WindowsPowerShell
```

or inside the installation folder of PowerShell, which can be figured out by:

```
cd $PSHOME\
```

Answer (score 3):

If your python 3.x is already in your PATH and you've already deleted any previous python3 versions from your machine (and PATH), you just need to run:

`mklink "C:\path\to\Python3\python3.exe" "C:\path\to\Python3\python.exe"`.

If you're running multiple versions of python3, you can set the symlink to whatever you want:

`mklink "C:\path\to\Python3\pythonXYZ.exe" "C:\path\to\Python3\python.exe"`.

Restart cmd prompt and `python3 --version` or `pythonXYZ --version` will print your linked version

Comment: I use `mklink python3.exe python.exe`
and its work for me

Answer (score 2):

If you are still wondering how to do it, Here is one workaround!
Create a PowerShell file named `python3.ps1` and inside that just type `python` and save it anywhere you like.
Copy that path and add that path to the Environment path.
Now you are ready to go!
Just type `python3` and it runs python.
you can also use the `python` command to use python.

Comment: For me this doesn't work unless I type `python3.ps1`, which defeats the whole purpose of it...

Comment: Maybe you didn't add the script to the environment variable? Would you mind commenting on the output of the terminal when typing `python3`?

Comment: I added the path where the script is located to the environment variable, not the script itself... it doesn't make sense to add a file to a PATH variable, does it?

Comment: Yes, you need to add path to the environment variable not the file itself. And it only works from powershell as far as I know. If you want to run the command from cmd, you need to add .bat file also. It may work after that.

Comment: it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

For people ending up here while using powershell, this is another way to create symlinks.

Caveat: `Requires Admin rights or group policy that allows this on normal mortal users`

- Open Admin / Link creation capable powershell terminal
- Run

```
$venv=((get-command python).source | Get-ItemProperty).DirectoryName;New-Item -Path $venv -Name "python3.exe" -Value "$venv\python.exe" -ItemType SymbolicLink
```

If you work no a virtual environment, run this first:

```
.\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```