# How to add Anacond's python to path and run it inside a given terminal

Tags: windows, python, path, anaconda

I solved my own question but I thought I'd share my problem and answer for anyone else having this issue.

In a nutshell, I installed Anaconda and I wanted it to be my one and only source for Python. I know how to use the navigator GUI and the Anaconda prompt but I wanted to be able to run vanilla python from other shells like powershell, command prompt, gitbash, wsl, etc especially as I have those integrated with VS Code, my main editor.

I located what I thought was the proper python.exe file (2 locations `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` and `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`) and added them to both to system path and then when that didn't work, to user path. When I typed python it opened up the MS Store for installing python.

That could have been enough of a clue but it took one more hint for me to figure it out. When I navigated to the directory in question in powershell and hit python, it still opened up the store. I mistakenly thought that for some reason this app/program just wasn't designed to be open via the terminal, if such a thing is possible, because when I double clicked on it in the GUI, it opened in the Anaconda terminal. I thought it called some other program that I had to find. Well, I found the answer. I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In brief, you have to disable windows from hijacking your intended use of the Python command and redirecting you to store.

**Edit:** This is the exact way (after you get Anaconda installed and working as its own program in it's own native shell environments). Go into windows **Settings>Apps>Apps Execution Alias** and toggle off *App Installer (python.exe)* and *App Installer (python3.exe)*. It was that easy- all GUI work.

BTW more on how/why Windows set this up this way can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/).

This question was kind of answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor/1461471#1461471) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-window-store-when-i-type-python) as well but I thought I'd share my answer as it refers to Anaconda's python explicitly and it works as expected.

Comment: Please add the complete instructions you used to fix it to your answer. As it is nobody knows what you actually did to fix the issue.