# Corrupted python.exe file

Tags: windows, python

Whenever the command "where python" is executed a path is shown that leads me to the .exe file. Problem is that whenever I try to delete the file this window pops up:

[image]

I've tried installing python from that file but to no avail. A bunch of 0 kB files spring up but again I can't delete .exe. 
How can I safely delete the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typing “python” on Windows 10 (version 1903) command prompt opens Microsoft store](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor)

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate.  The file you are attempting to delete isn't corrupt, it's simply currently in use.  See the duplicate how to properly get rid of the file.

Comment: Do you mean files obtained by `dir %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python*`?

Comment: Yes and thank you for the response and it is indeed a duplicate but using del <name_of_file> (in this case python.exe) solved the problem