# "python" typed in powershell does not work although it is in the PATH

Tags: powershell, python, path

I'm trying to add python to my PATH to use it in the powershell. `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe` is in the PATH. I removed the alias that triggered the microsoft app store to open by removing the aliases as indicated in [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor). However now, when I typed `python` in the powershell, the following message occurs:
`the term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`
I also tried `.\python` as advised in a previously deleted answer without more success

What shall I do?

Comment: The dup talks about chrome.exe but it's the same principle. Remove the exe from the path entry. It should only list the folder that the exe is in.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your system variables.  I would expect the path to Python to come before the `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\`.  Please [edit] your question and include the required information necessary to answer your question.  Since the linked question has 8 answers you will have to be more specific about which solution you actually used.  Hopefully, all you did was disable app execution aliases, and installed Python 3 and added it's installation directory your system variable.

Comment: many thanks @n8te. I removed `\python.exe` from the PATH and it worked