# Remove Windows 10 Python 'App Execution Alias'

Tags: windows-10, python

I am trying to permanently remove the `python.exe` 'App Execution Alias' from the **UI Screen**. This is not about disabling the Alias it is specifically about removal of the item from the list of items on the **App Execution Alias UI**

**Note:** this is not the same as 'similar' questions like: [Typing “python” on Windows 10 (version 1903) command prompt opens Microsoft store](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor) . I want to remove the item from the 'List of Items' shown on the **App Execution Alias** UI Screen.

Windows 'App Execution Aliases' are located under the path `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`. When toggling the slider in the Windows UI for App Execution Aliases the backing `python.exe` disappears.

The backing registry entries for the UI Screen are supposedly located under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` (also under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` etc.)

However none of these locations contain the `python.exe` alias (other aliases do exist in these locations, so I believe this is the correct registry path)

So does anyone know how to remove the `python.exe` alias item from the list of items that appears on the **App Execution Alias UI Screen** ?

Comment: (1) Do you see `python.exe` in *Settings > Apps > App execution aliases*? (2) You could also search it in the registry using [RegScanner](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html).

Comment: this is not about disabling the alias... I want it removed from the list of items displayed on the App Execution Alias UI Screen

Comment: (1) Will verify if it's still there, (2) If found, then `RegScanner` will find it in the registry.

Comment: [I am going with "you can't" since it's baked into the kernel.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/).  You can disable the alias but removing it entirely is something else entirely.

Comment: Some aliases in that list in the Settings app can be found in the registry, but some aliases in that list originate from AppX packages. App execution alias is one of the 'extensions' that an AppX package can contain. These make it possible to install command-line programs from the Microsoft Store. The executable becomes available after installing the app, without having to adjust your `PATH` environment variable. The `python.exe` and `python3.exe` aliases come from the Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller package. Unfortunately, this package cannot be uninstalled.