# override windows store open action when launching python in powershell

Tags: python, windows-11, environment-variables, path

`C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe` is in my path but when I execute python in powershell it automatically opens up Microsoft Store which is anyway blocked by the admin.

How do I override the default path, which apparently fires up Windows Store?

[Latest Python was installed manually by me:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTudW.png)

> ```
> PS D:\> C:\Users\CURRENT_USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
> Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb 7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> ```

Comment: [Have you installed Python? By default unless you disable the behavior Windows will attempt to install Python from the Windows Store when it’s not installed](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor/1442940#1442940)

Comment: Yes - edited original post.

Comment: Have you disabled App execution aliases for Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typing “python” on Windows 10 (version 1903) command prompt opens Microsoft store](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor).  I was waiting for confirmation you had not disabled Application execution aliases before flagging this question as a duplicate. The answer you recieved forced my hand to flag it sooner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do this :

- Open "Settings > Apps > Apps & features*
- Click "App execution aliases"
- Scroll to the bottom of the list and uncheck the entries for
  "App Installer - python.exe" and "App Installer - python3.exe".

The effect is immediate.

Comment: Correct answer, but I had to search the settings for "alias" to find "App execution aliases".